# C++ get column vector from a Matrix

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, vector

I have defined a matrix like this in my code

```
*matrix1 = new int[*matrix1rows * *matrix1columns];
*matrix2 = new int[*matrix2rows * *matrix2columns];
```

Now I need to save the columns of the matrix as a single vector to multiply two matrices.
For example if I have a matrix like this:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 1 2 3
```

I want to get every single column in a vector for example

```
1
5
9
```

I already have created a loop to get the rows as a vector but now I need the same thing for the columns but I have no idea how to do that.

This is my loop to get the row vectors. But now I need to get the column vectors of the matrix2 to multiply it with the row vectors of matrix1. I can´t change the definition of the matrices.

```
for (int j = 0; j < matrix1rows; j++) {
  for (int i = 0; i < matrix1columns; i++) {
      printf("%i ", matrix1[(j * matrix1columns) + i]);
  }
}
```

How can I get the columns of the matrix with a loop?

Answer (score 1):

Interchange the row label with the column label, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix1columns; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < matrix1rows; j++) {
      printf("%i ", matrix1[(j * matrix1columns) + i]);
  }
}
```